# Extend / override page element in elgg 1.6

Tags: php, elgg

I would like to know how do I extend owner_block page element in elgg framework. I want it to display differently depending on module using it. Differences are not only in different menu item names, but much greater. I created page_elements folder in my plugin views directory, but it changed owner_block on every page in every module, and I want it (for example) to display my way only in search module, but not in dashboard.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the if condition

Like

```
if(get_context() == 'search') {
// then show the updates
}else{
// just blank
}
```

Thanks..